What weapons are exclusive to Halo Infinite multiplayer?
I know that a lot of the weopons aren't available in multiplayer and only in campaign.
But I was wondering the opposite. Are there any weapons that are exclusive to multiplayer? (Meaning that they're not available in campaign?)
